# sub sub-menus are appearing in all table cells vue js

Tags: vue.js

please run the snippet at the end of script(not the first one at the end of html)

```html
<!-- Include the library in the page -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.0-beta.1/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
       <th>Menu</th>
           <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedMenu" value="0" />
          All</label>
       <th>Submenu</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for="menu in menus" :key="menu.id">
             <td>
                        <label>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            :value="menu.id" @change="setSelectedMenu($event,menu.id)"
                          />@{{ menu.menuName }}
                          </label
                        >
                      </td>
                      <td >
                        <ul>
                          <li
        v-for="submenu in filteredProduct"
                         :key="submenu.id"  v-if="menu.id == submenu.menuId">
                        
                                <input type="checkbox" :value="submenu.id"  />
                                 <label  >{{ submenu.subMenuName }}  </label>
                                
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </td>
                     
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
  
</div>
```

```js
console.clear()
// New VueJS instance
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    menus: [{
        id: 1,
        menuName: "Tech 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        menuName: "Tech 2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        menuName: "Tech 3"
      }
    ],
    selectedMenu: [],
    submenus: [{
        id: 1,
        menuId: 1,
        subMenuName: "architecture"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        menuId: 1,
        subMenuName: "Electrical"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        menuId: 1,
        subMenuName: "Electronics"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        menuId: 2,
        subMenuName: "IEM"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        menuId: 3,
        subMenuName: "CIVIL"
      }
    ],
    selectedSubMenu: [],

    subsubmenus: [{
        id: 1,
        submenuId: 1,
        sub_subMenuName: "becm"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        submenuId: 1,
        sub_subMenuName: "ece"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        submenuId: 4,
        sub_subMenuName: "EEE"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        submenuId: 2,
        sub_subMenuName: "CSE"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        submenuId: 3,
        sub_subMenuName: "MSE"
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredProduct: function() {
      const app = this,
        menu = app.selectedMenu;

      if (menu.includes("0")) {
        return app.submenus;
      } else {
        return app.submenus.filter(function(item) {
          return menu.indexOf(item.menuId) >= 0;
        });
      }
    },
    filteredSub_submenu: function() {
      const app = this,
        submenu = app.selectedSubMenu;

      if (submenu.includes("0")) {
        return app.subsubmenus;
      } else {
        return app.subsubmenus.filter(function(item) {
          return submenu.indexOf(item.submenuId) >= 0;
        });
      }
    }

  },
  methods: {

    setSelectedMenu: function(event, menu_id) {

      if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedMenu.push(menu_id);
      } else {
        var index = this.selectedMenu.indexOf(menu_id);
        this.selectedMenu.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    setSelectedSubMenu: function(event, submenu_id) {

      if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedSubMenu.push(submenu_id);
      } else {
        var index = this.selectedSubMenu.indexOf(submenu_id);
        this.selectedSubMenu.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include the library in the page -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.0-beta.1/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Menu</th>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedMenu" value="0" />
          All</label>
        <th>Submenu</th>
        <th>Sub-Submenu</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="menu in menus" :key="menu.id">
        <td>
          <label>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            :value="menu.id" @change="setSelectedMenu($event,menu.id)"
                          />@{{ menu.menuName }}
                          </label
                        >
                      </td>
                      <td >
                        <ul>
                          <li
        v-for="submenu in filteredProduct"
                         :key="submenu.id" >
                        
                                
                                 <label v-if="menu.id == submenu.menuId" >
                                 <input type="checkbox" :value="submenu.id"
                               @change="setSelectedSubMenu($event,submenu.id)" />{{ submenu.subMenuName }}  </label>

          </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="subsubmenu in filteredSub_submenu" :key="subsubmenu.id">
              <label>
                                <input
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  :value="subsubmenu.id"
                                />
                                {{ subsubmenu.sub_subMenuName }}
                              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

I am working on a menu permission project using vue.js. I have some submenus which are child of different menus. I have also some sub sub-menus which are child of sub-menus. When I click on any menu the submenus are appearing on the right cell but when I click on a sub-menu, the sub sub-menus are appearing in all cells. how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a relationship between ***subsubmenus*** and ***menus***, according the relationship between ***subsubmenus*** and ***submenus***.

Add a new object in ***subsubmenus***:

```
subsubmenus: [
  {
    id: 1,
    menuId: 1, // NEW
    submenuId: 1,
    sub_subMenuName: "becm"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    menuId: 1, // NEW
    submenuId: 1,
    sub_subMenuName: "ece"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    menuId: 2, // NEW
    submenuId: 4,
    sub_subMenuName: "EEE"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    menuId: 1, // NEW
    submenuId: 2,
    sub_subMenuName: "CSE"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    menuId: 1, // NEW
    submenuId: 3,
    sub_subMenuName: "MSE"
  }
]
```

Add a **v-if** statement inside `<label>` (where you print the Sub-Submenus). Like this:

```
<td>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="subsubmenu in filteredSub_submenu" :key="subsubmenu.id">
      <label v-if="menu.id == subsubmenu.menuId">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :value="subsubmenu.id"
        />
        {{ subsubmenu.sub_subMenuName }}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</td>
```